# Why am I getting name 'twitter' is not defined even when I imported twitter module?

Tags: python, twitter

I am following twitter help documentation and tried to get access to a friends statuses. But I keep getting error in the last line. The error is NameError: name 'twitter' is not defined. I am using REST, python 2.7.8 on windows. I am writing my code on Notepad++ and then importing it in cmd.This is my code:

```
from twitter import *
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''
x = twitter.statuses.user_timeline(id = "ArpitMittal108")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought twitter referred to the library twitter. But it was actually an initialisation of Twitter class. So if I add this line.                                                      twitter = Twitter( auth = OAuth(access_token, access_token_secret, consumer_key, consumer_secret))`
It works fine.

Comment: Ok deleted my answer since you got there on your own :).

Comment: Half of it is making the question easy to read, but maybe also include what you have tried? idk